# ajax does not send info from client to server side

Tags: ajax

I have an ajax on client side:

```
 $("#TIPUL_ACTULUI").change(function(){
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '<c:url value="/"/>searchByAct',
            data:{act:selectedText},
            dataType: 'json',
            context:this,
            success:function(data){
                $('#DREVIZ').html(data);
            },
            error:function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState=0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0)
                    return;
            }
        });
    });
```

and on server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchByAct", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelMap acte(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "act") String act){
        ModelMap model=null;
        model.clear();
        PortalUserDetails user = (PortalUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        ArrayOfSlSordIdRegInfo arrayActe = ixService.searchActeForCUI(user.getPunctDeLucru().getCnpCuiOE(),
            String.valueOf(user.getPunctDeLucru().getIdPDL()));

        Map<String, List<SlSordIdRegInfo>> comboItemsMap4 = new HashMap<String, List<SlSordIdRegInfo>>();
        comboItemsMap4.put(Constants.CHEIE_SORD_DREVIZ, arrayActe.getSlSordIdRegInfo());

        model.addAttribute("comboItemsMap4", comboItemsMap4);

        return model;
    }
```

my problem is that the compiller doesn't reach the server side. What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing is coming to mind when i am looking at the code is to change the `url` into:

```
url: '/searchByAct',
```

Comment: my link is: http://localhost:8080/portal-webapp/cerere/detaliiDM/5/0 and I get the error: POST http://localhost:8080/portal-webapp/searchByAct 404 Not Found. I need to enter on server side with a breakpoint but it doesn't enter there... I tried with the simple url but it also doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that URL is correct try to stringify the 'data' parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({act:selectedText}),
    ...
}
```